# Apache Kafka 2.3 + Node.js 10.15 + Consumer + Producer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to connect to a remote Apache Kafka server from a remote machine using nodejs. I am unable to produce a message on the desired kafka topic from the nodejs code. I am also unable to consume any data from the topic as well.

I am using **Apache-kafka version 2.12_2.2.1** along with **Java 8**. I am also using **node version 8.11.0**. I started the zookeeper server and kafka server as well.  I created a topic and a producer and consumer locally on the ubuntu machine to check the working of apache-kafka and I was able to produce and consume messages on a topic. When I tried the same from a remote windows machine using nodejs I was unable to get any results. I also tried adding my server to the listeners and advertised.listeners in the config/server.properties file but was still not working.

**My Question:**
I wanted to establish remote connection to kafka server from node js and consume the produced messages under a topic.
Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks.

Following is the producer code:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Producer = kafka.Producer,
    KeyedMessage = kafka.KeyedMessage,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: '192.168.1.104:9092'}),
    producer = new Producer(client),
    payloads = [
        { topic: 'topic1', messages: 'hi', partition: 2 }
    ];
producer.on('ready', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
    setInterval(() => {
        producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }, 1000);
});

producer.on('error', function (err) {console.error('Error occurred:', err);})
```

Following is the consumer code:

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: '192.168.1.104:9092'}),
    consumer = new Consumer(client,
        [{ topic: 'topic1', offset: 0}],
        {
            autoCommit: false
        }
    );

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});

consumer.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error:',err);
})

consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function (err) {
    console.log('offsetOutOfRange:',err);
})
```

listed the response messages from the node js terminal

For producer code:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\nodejs>node kafka-producer.js
Connected
undefined
```

For consumer code:

```
Error: { TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms    at new TimeoutError (C:\Users\user\Documents\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\lib\errors\TimeoutError.js:6:9)
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\user\Documents\nodejs\node_modules\kafka-node\lib\kafkaClient.js:491:14)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5) message:
'Request timed out after 30000ms' }
```

I have attached the server.properties file below:

```
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.88:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.88:9092,
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1


############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances dur$
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Comment: Please share the server.properties file

Comment: @cricket_007 I have attached the server.properties file. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have multiple lines of both listeners and advertised listeners? Note: both `listeners` lines are commented, so not actually doing anything, but should just be PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried changing it to PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 and got the following error                                                                                                                           `ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: advertised.listeners cannot use the nonroutable meta-address 0.0.0.0. Use a routable IP address.`

Comment: I said the listeners should be that, not the advertised ones. Those should be the external IP of the machine

Comment: @cricket_007 I had tried changing listeners to that and it gave me the same error. However I was able to find some other code that worked a charm. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Great! Feel free to provide your working solution below as an answer to your own post

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes shall do that! Please feel free to check the answer and please let me know of any changes or corrections if any. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the following codes. I have currently set the codes to produce incremental numbers to test if the consumer is working perfectly.

**Producer Code in Node js**:

```
const kafka = require('kafka-node');
const kafka_topic = 'sample';
try {
  const Producer = kafka.Producer;
  const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: '192.168.1.246:9092'});
  const producer = new Producer(client);

console.log("Producer Initialised..");



  producer.on('ready', function() {
      let num = 0;
      setInterval(() => {
        let payloads = [
            {
              topic: 'sample',
              messages: num
            }
          ];
          producer.send(payloads, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: broker update failed');
            } else {
              console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: broker update success');
            }
          });
          num++;
      }, 2000);

  });

  producer.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log('[kafka-producer -> '+kafka_topic+']: connection errored');
    throw err;
  });
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

**Consumer code is Node js**:

```
let kafka =require("kafka-node");

const client = new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: '192.168.1.246:9092'});

console.log("Initialised..");
const topics = [{
    topic: 'sample',
    offset: 0, //default 0
    partition: 0 // default 0
 }];

const options = {
    autoCommit: true
};

const consumer = new kafka.Consumer(client, topics, options);

consumer.setMaxListeners(11);

consumer.on("ready", function(message) {
    console.log("I am ready");
});
consumer.on("message", function(message) {
    console.log("Hey got message");
    // console.log(message);

   console.log("Message: ", message.value);
});

consumer.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("error", err);
});
```

Make the following changes to the **config/server.properties** file in the kafka folder.
Note:- Add the IP address of the current machine you are working on that has kafka and zookeeper installed in order to enable use of kafka from remote machines over network.

```
Server.properties file

 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.246:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,


# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1


############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances dur$
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

This works perfectly over remote machines as well and has been tested with node versions **10.15.0** and **8.11.0** and Kafka current LTS version **2.3.0** and Zookeeper version **3.5.5**

Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: If you want Kafka data to be persistent, do not store it in `/tmp`

Comment: @cricket_007 Great Thanks!

Comment: @BhaskarSen: Thanks for helping community with such detailed answer.